# MySQL Join with Insert combined?

Tags: mysql, join, insert

Is it possible to have an INSERT from a reference table if something exists there?

Say this is the query to insert some data...

```
INSERT INTO  `Test`.`Items` (
`Name` ,
`Type` ,
`Number`
)
VALUES (
'Pork',  'Sausage', 6
);
```

And that I have a lookup table called "Lookup" that contains two columns.  "Type" and "Number".  What I want is that if something exists in the "Lookup" table in this instance for Type Sausage then to pull in the "Number" field from the lookup table instead of inserting the 6 in the INSERT statement.

[image]

Hope that is clear!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Test.Items 
    (Name, Type, Number)
    SELECT 'Pork', 'Sausage', COALESCE(l.Number, 6)
        FROM Lookup l
        WHERE l.Type = 'Sausage'
```

**EDIT**: Additional samples based on comments below.

Using `UNION ALL` to string inserts together:

```
INSERT INTO Test.Items 
    (Name, Type, Number)
    SELECT 'Pork', 'Sausage', COALESCE(l.Number, 6)
        FROM Lookup l
        WHERE l.Type = 'Sausage'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Halibut', 'Fish', COALESCE(l.Number, 7)
        FROM Lookup l
        WHERE l.Type = 'Fish'
```

Using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpItems (
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Type VARCHAR(255),
    Number INT
)

INSERT INTO tmpItems
    (Name, Type, Number)
    VALUES ('Pork', 'Sausage', 6)
INSERT INTO tmpItems
    (Name, Type, Number)
    VALUES ('Halibut', 'Fish', 7)

INSERT INTO Test.Items 
    (Name, Type, Number)
    SELECT t.Name, t.Type, COALESCE(l.Number, t.Number)
        FROM tmpItems t
            LEFT JOIN Lookup l
                ON t.Type = l.Type
```

Comment: That is brilliant, never had seen the COALESCE command either, very nice!

Comment: If I wanted multiple lookup tables say for another value, how would I structure that?  So another table Lookup2 for example where I (using this example) lookup the Name

Comment: @Lee: There are a couple of approaches. You could string together SELECT statements with a UNION ALL operator or, if you have a large enough number of values to insert, you might want to populate a temporary table with all of your values and then JOIN against the Lookup. I'll provide samples of each for you.

Comment: I actually have an issue where that if the lookup doesn't exist then the whole insert doesn't work!  This is based on the first sample.  Just posted this as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945332/mysql-insert-with-lookup-when-null