# MySQL INSERT with lookup when null

Tags: mysql, insert

I have the following query that works when the Lookup table has something in it.  However if "z.a" doesn't equal anything the INSERT fails.  Why would this be?

```
 INSERT INTO dataTable(
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    i,
    j,
    k,
    l,
    m,
    n,
    o,
    p
)SELECT
    '000003',
    COALESCE(z.Registration, 'REG6'),
    'PFTEST',
    '1',
    '1',
    '37000.0',
    '148.0',
    '439.8',
    '1312475688',
    '0',
    '54',
    COALESCE(z.TypeCode, 'A555'),
    '',
    '1173',
    '0',
    'nJ'
FROM
    LookupTable z
WHERE
    z.a = '000003'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I removed the WHERE completely and performed selects within the VALUES direct. Works very well

Answer (score 1):

The outer insert query will insert anything that the select returns - if it returns nothing, then what is there to insert? This is expected behavior. Anything else would be insane - what should get inserted if there's nothing available to be inserted? Should the insert query make up data?

Comment: Well the purpose was that the data is already there but I want to override the values in the Lookup table if there is something there, thus using the Coalesce

Comment: Try running the select query by itself... it'll return nothing. Until you can massage it into a format where it DOES return something, the insert query is basically useless fluff.

Comment: Well I know that query returns nothing, this is part of a larger loop  and I just discovered this!  This works when there is a value but when there isn't a value I want it to use the other values like "A555"

Comment: The coalesce will never kick in, because the where clause prevents anything from ever being returned. You might try `where z.a='0003' or z.a is null`, or whatever construct does let it return a row even if there is no matching z.a record.

Comment: Precisely the effect I am after with the is null statement however it still does not work!  Probably as it won't do the insert as no rows are returned.  Is there another way to achieve this?